# Facebook Dom Placeholder on Password

Tags: javascript, facebook

Facebook has a "Dom Placeholder" on their Password field when logging on. When I click on the input for the password, the placeholder disappears and allows me to type my password "masked".

Is this Javascript related and how would I go on replicating this script?

Comment: yes it is javascript related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it can be done via JavaScript, but some browsers also support it natively. The `placeholder` attribute is an HTML5 addition; certain browsers (such as WebKit-based browsers) support it already.

### Example using jQuery 1.4

```
<!-- this will work automatically for some browsers -->
<input type="text" placeholder="enter some text">


<!-- script for browsers which don't support it natively -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$.fn.placeholder = function(){

  // quit if there's support for html5 placeholder
  if (this[0] && 'placeholder' in document.createElement('input')) return; 

  return this
    .live('focusin',function(){

      if ($(this).val() === $(this).attr('placeholder')) {
        $(this).val('');
      }

    }).live('focusout',function(){

      if ($(this).val() === ''){
        $(this).val( $(this).attr('placeholder') );
      }_  
    });
}

$('input[placeholder]').placeholder();
</script>
```

Note: code was copied from [this Pastie](http://pastie.org/783420) linked from [jQuery 1.4 hawtness](http://jquery14.com/day-05/jquery-1-4-hawtness-1-with-paul-irish). I haven't verified that it works across browsers. You can find other JavaScript solutions on Google if you don't use jQuery.

Answer (score -1):

There is a jQuery plugin that does this:
http://plugins.jquery.com/node/14237

Comment: While the suggested plugin may work, the problem is that it is not documented and is not at all configurable. In this case, it would have been better to simply call out to a code sample.